# Probability of finite heads in coin flips

Tags: probability, borel-cantelli-lemmas

$\mathbb{P}[X_{n}$ is head $] = p_{n}$.

$F$ is the event that only finitely many heads are observed.

How do I prove $\mathbb{P}[F]=1$ iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_{n} <\infty$

I am confused about this question from my text book. How do I go about doing this proof.

It seems obvious to me that if there are finitely many heads then their probabilities for each one is a finite number?

Please could I have help and not the full answer. Thanks!

I assume it has something to do with the Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Comment: For the first step: can you state the Borel–Cantelli Lemma?

Comment: Let $E_{n}$  be a sequence of events then if the sum of the probabilities between 1 and infinity of each of the probabilities is less than infinity then the probability of infinitely many occuring is 0.

Would I literally just need to prove the borel-cantelli lemma and then just say by this lemma it is true?

Comment: Yes, or just quote the lemma if it's already proved!

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: This is a false statement.  Likely you are omitting important additional assumptions, and/or you are only proving one direction.